# Apache Atlas quickstart - kafka error

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-atlas

Env: no kerberos, no ranger, no hdfs. EC2 with ssl.

Getting this error after running `$ATLAS_HOME/bin/quick_start.py https://$componentPrivateDNSRecord:21443` with correct user/pass

```
Creating sample types:
Created type [DB]
Created type [Table]
Created type [StorageDesc]
Created type [Column]
Created type [LoadProcess]
Created type [View]
Created type [JdbcAccess]
Created type [ETL]
Created type [Metric]
Created type [PII]
Created type [Fact]
Created type [Dimension]
Created type [Log Data]

Creating sample entities:

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:105)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.method(WebResource.java:634)
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPIWithResource(AtlasBaseClient.java:334)
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPIWithResource(AtlasBaseClient.java:311)
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPI(AtlasBaseClient.java:199)
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasClientV2.createEntity(AtlasClientV2.java:277)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.createInstance(QuickStartV2.java:339)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.createDatabase(QuickStartV2.java:362)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.createEntities(QuickStartV2.java:268)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.runQuickstart(QuickStartV2.java:150)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.main(QuickStartV2.java:132)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:253)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
        ... 14 more
No sample data added to Apache Atlas Server.
```

Relevant code:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-atlas/blob/master/webapp/src/main/java/org/apache/atlas/examples/QuickStartV2.java

```
#This works
    quickStartV2.createTypes();
#This errors
    quickStartV2.createEntities();
```

First I thought atlas->kafka connectivity was issue but then I see:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-160-187-181 logs]$ cat atlas_kafka_setup.log
2018-07-25 00:06:14,923 INFO  - [main:] ~ Looking for atlas-application.properties in classpath (ApplicationProperties:78)
2018-07-25 00:06:14,926 INFO  - [main:] ~ Loading atlas-application.properties from file:/home/ec2-user/atlas/distro/target/apache-atlas-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/apache-atlas-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/atlas-application.properties (ApplicationProperties:91)
2018-07-25 00:06:16,512 WARN  - [main:] ~ Attempting to create topic ATLAS_HOOK (AtlasTopicCreator:72)
2018-07-25 00:06:17,004 WARN  - [main:] ~ Created topic ATLAS_HOOK with partitions 1 and replicas 1 (AtlasTopicCreator:119)
2018-07-25 00:06:17,004 WARN  - [main:] ~ Attempting to create topic ATLAS_ENTITIES (AtlasTopicCreator:72)
2018-07-25 00:06:17,024 WARN  - [main:] ~ Created topic ATLAS_ENTITIES with partitions 1 and replicas 1 (AtlasTopicCreator:119)



2018-07-25 01:49:45,147 DEBUG - [main:] ~ Calling API [ GET : api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs ]  (AtlasBaseClient:319)
2018-07-25 01:49:45,147 DEBUG - [main:] ~ Attempting to configure HTTPS connection using client configuration (SecureClientUtils$4:221)
2018-07-25 01:49:45,166 INFO  - [main:] ~ Unable to configure HTTPS connection from configuration.  Leveraging JDK properties. (SecureClientUtils$4:240)
2018-07-25 01:49:45,269 DEBUG - [main:] ~ API https://mydns:21443/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs?name=Dimension returned status 200 (AtlasBaseClient:337)
2018-07-25 01:49:45,270 DEBUG - [main:] ~ Calling API [ GET : api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs ]  (AtlasBaseClient:319)
2018-07-25 01:49:45,271 DEBUG - [main:] ~ Attempting to configure HTTPS connection using client configuration (SecureClientUtils$4:221)
2018-07-25 01:49:45,291 INFO  - [main:] ~ Unable to configure HTTPS connection from configuration.  Leveraging JDK properties. (SecureClientUtils$4:240)
2018-07-25 01:49:45,450 DEBUG - [main:] ~ API https://mydns:21443/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs?name=Log+Data returned status 200 (AtlasBaseClient:337)
2018-07-25 01:49:45,455 DEBUG - [main:] ~ Calling API [ POST : api/atlas/v2/entity ] <== AtlasEntityWithExtInfo{entity=AtlasEntity{AtlasStruct{typeName='DB', attributes=[owner:John ETL, createTime:1532483385453, name:Sales, description:sales database, locationuri:hdfs://host:8000/apps/warehouse/sales]}guid='-6466195619848', status=null, createdBy='null', updatedBy='null', createTime=null, updateTime=null, version=0, relationshipAttributes=[], classifications=[], },AtlasEntityExtInfo{referredEntities={}}} (AtlasBaseClient:319)
2018-07-25 01:49:45,455 DEBUG - [main:] ~ Attempting to configure HTTPS connection using client configuration (SecureClientUtils$4:221)
2018-07-25 01:49:45,474 INFO  - [main:] ~ Unable to configure HTTPS connection from configuration.  Leveraging JDK properties. (SecureClientUtils$4:240)


2018-07-25 01:49:33,256  Audit: myuser/10.160.189.35-10.160.189.35 performed request POST https://mydns:21443/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs (10.160.187.181) at time 2018-07-25T01:49Z
2018-07-25 01:49:45,445  Audit: myuser/10.160.189.35-10.160.189.35 performed request GET https://mydns:21443/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs?name=Log+Data (10.160.187.181) at time 2018-07-25T01:49Z
2018-07-25 01:49:45,678  Audit: myuser/10.160.189.35-10.160.189.35 performed request POST https://mydns:21443/api/atlas/v2/entity (10.160.187.181) at time 2018-07-25T01:49Z
```

The 2 topics are returned by this:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

atlas' `application.log` does have this, not sure why:

```
2018-07-25 02:18:14,991 DEBUG - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ Give up sending metadata request since no node is available (NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:625)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,018 DEBUG - [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1:] ~ Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request (NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:644)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,018 DEBUG - [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1:] ~ Initiating connection to node -1 at localhost:9027. (NetworkClient:496)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,018 DEBUG - [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1:] ~ Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected (Selector:345)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:51)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:73)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:309)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:134)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,018 DEBUG - [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1:] ~ Node -1 disconnected. (NetworkClient:463)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,018 DEBUG - [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1:] ~ Give up sending metadata request since no node is available (NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:625)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,092 DEBUG - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request (NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:644)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,092 DEBUG - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ Initiating connection to node -1 at localhost:9027. (NetworkClient:496)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,092 DEBUG - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected (Selector:345)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:51)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:73)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:309)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:134)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:183)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:973)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:937)
        at org.apache.atlas.kafka.AtlasKafkaConsumer.receive(AtlasKafkaConsumer.java:63)
        at org.apache.atlas.kafka.AtlasKafkaConsumer.receive(AtlasKafkaConsumer.java:55)
        at org.apache.atlas.notification.NotificationHookConsumer$HookConsumer.doWork(NotificationHookConsumer.java:305)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,092 DEBUG - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ Node -1 disconnected. (NetworkClient:463)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,092 DEBUG - [NotificationHookConsumer thread-0:] ~ Give up sending metadata request since no node is available (NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:625)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,119 DEBUG - [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1:] ~ Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request (NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:644)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,119 DEBUG - [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1:] ~ Initiating connection to node -1 at localhost:9027. (NetworkClient:496)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,119 DEBUG - [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1:] ~ Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected (Selector:345)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:51)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:73)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:309)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:134)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,119 DEBUG - [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1:] ~ Node -1 disconnected. (NetworkClient:463)
2018-07-25 02:18:15,119 DEBUG - [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1:] ~ Give up sending metadata request since no node is available (NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater:625)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed it!

````
sed -i 's/atlas.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9027/atlas.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092/' $ATLAS_HOME/conf/atlas-application.properties```
````